# Getting value using Xpath from web page but cannot find the value

Tags: xpath

I write some python code and want to use xpath to read a value from webpage "http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/detail-quote.aspx?symbol=00371", but it shows "IndexError: list index out of range". After I check the page.content, I cannot find the value of field "P/B Ratio" in the content. Does anyone know how to get the "P/B Ratio" value? Thanks!

My code as below:

````
```
#TestXPath.py
from lxml import html
import requests
import threading

URL = 'http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/detail-quote.aspx?symbol=00371'
XPATH = '//*[@id="tbPBRatio"]/div[2]'

def getValue():
    page = requests.get(URL)
    print (page.content)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    value = tree.xpath(XPATH)

    print('value={0!s}'.format(value[0]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getValue()
```
````

[Captured an image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGZAW.jpg)

The part of the output of page.content is here:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['a2._setAccount', 'UA-129684769-1']); _gaq.push(['a2._trackPageview']);</script><meta property="fb:app_id" content="280135662816939" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="keywords" content="HK Stocks, Quote, Detailed Quote, Fund, Warrants, CBBCs, Call, Put, News, Technical Chart, Blocked Trade, HK Indices, CN Indices" /><meta name="description" content="HK Stock Detail Quote provides information including Free HK-share Real-time Quote, HK-share Chart, HK-share Historical Performance, HK-share Technical Chart, Related A-share Quote, HK-share PE Ratio, HK-share Yield, HK-share Earnings Per Share, HK-share Dividend Payout, HK-share PB Ratio, HK-share Moneyflow, HK-share NAV, A + H + ADR, HK-share News, HK-share related warrants, HK-share related CBBC" /><link href="/en/favicon.ico?v=1.2.0" rel="icon" /><link href="/en/favicon.ico?v=1.2.0" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /><title>
Detail Quote
</title></head> <body id="stock" class="eng resizeable"> <div id="divFSMask" style="position:absolute; filter:alpha(opacity=80); zoom:1; opacity:0.8; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; background:black; height:100%; z-index:100; display:none"></div> <div id="CrazyiPadPopup"><script type='text/javascript'>OA_show('Crazy_iPad_popup');</script></div> <div class="div980"></div> <script type="text/javascript">
is980Mode = $(".div980").is(":visible");
curWidth980Mode = is980Mode;
$(window).resize(function () {
is980Mode = $(".div980").is(":visible");
});
</script> <form method="post" action="detail-quote.aspx?symbol=00371" id="mainForm"> <div class="aspNetHidden"> <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="Z9MEfrcXHWZHLrGNyFqv+7SMlO6SiAMa7mXGDMSld4HEXzCSEoFrPdihSEdNmeLlfp2baKFj4zokP6U4qIkQHqDHMWXV/jmGUoqV4SMh5eVDRMAt9R/uTpjoNRENJ1gJvpq1WfDuqhOk4bgLGuMIkVrrNVEeulw+uPlpfk6+IKGUlf+oGGm8+uEqAJVbXuwF7hwKJVAhb+gPc1EHEzmjBIzKhwYZjVkVemPXQREWHgctAZfQ3kZ+m/+hQp5V6+DW/SNkXGj9RrdVnH8CGZW3RXbgouS/d8cUOOFkzBEApi5R5S+TDmf5xuXNPFuJk256LtjbwXKQUVvM14wt+6GuXYyBpKnaRmwypcbUrmbtCd0dN0Y0" /> </div> <div class="container"> </div> <div class="container" style="position:relative; z-index:3;" id="divMasterHead"> <div id="topPanel"> <div class="blue-line"> <div class="container"> <div class="float_l AASTOCKSHome" style="position:relative; top:10px; "> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px; padding-left:0px;" class="float_l icon_marginright" onclick="setHomepage()"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="curpointer" title="Set Homepage"><div class="header_icon_map icon_sethome jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron"></div></a></div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px; padding-left:0px;" class="float_l icon_marginright"><a href="/en/memberinfo/feedback.aspx" class="curpointer" title="Feedback"><div class="header_icon_map icon_contact jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron"></div></a></div> <div style="width:1px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; background-color:#006e97;" class="float_l icon_marginright"></div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" class="float_l icon_marginright lang-btn"><a id="bLang1" class="jshoverwithclass tc" hover="hoveron" href="javascript:toLang('tc')">繁</a></div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" class="float_l icon_marginright lang-btn"><a id="bLang2" class="jshoverwithclass sc" hover="hoveron" href="javascript:toLang('sc')">简</a></div> <div style="width:1px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; background-color:#006e97;" class="float_l icon_marginright"></div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px; padding-left:0px;" class="float_l icon_marginright"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/AAStocks.com.Limited/" class="curpointer" title="FACEBOOK FAN PAGE" target="_blank"><div class="header_icon_map icon_facebook jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron"></div></a></div> <div style="width:1px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; background-color:#006e97;" class="float_l icon_marginright"></div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" class="float_l icon_marginright"> <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/id368726182?mt=8" target="_blank" class="curpointer"> <div class="topslidebox"> <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1;"></div> <table><tr><td><div class="header_icon_map icon_topiphone"></div></td><td style="padding-left:9px;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">Market+ (iPhone)</span></td></tr></table> </div> </a> </div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" class="float_l icon_marginright"> <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aastocks.dzh&hl=en" target="_blank" class="curpointer"> <div class="topslidebox"> <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1;"></div> <table><tr><td><div class="header_icon_map icon_topandroid"></div></td><td style="padding-left:9px;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">Market+ (Android)</span></td></tr></table> </div> </a> </div> <div style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" class="float_l"> <a href="/en/mobile/default.aspx" class="curpointer"> <div class="topslidebox"> <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1;"></div> <table><tr><td><div class="header_icon_map icon_topmobile"></div></td><td style="padding-left:13px;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">Mobile Site</span></td></tr></table> </div> </a> </div> </div> <div class="tp-box float_r usq " onclick="window.location.href='/en/usq/default.aspx'"> <div class="bold jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron">US STOCKS</div> </div> <div class="tp-box float_r " onclick="window.location.href='/en/funds/default.aspx'"> <div class="bold jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron">FUNDS</div> </div> <div class="tp-box float_r " onclick="window.location.href='/en/forex/default.aspx'"> <div class="bold jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron">FOREX</div> </div> <div class="tp-box float_r " onclick="window.location.href='/en/cnhk/default.aspx'"> <div class="bold jshoverwithclass" hover="hoveron">SH/SZ-HK</div> </div> <div class="tp-box float_r sel" onclick="window.location.href='/en/'"> <div class="bold " hover="hoveron">HK STOCKS</div> </div> <div class="tp-box float_r aabest" onclick="gotoAABEST('https://www.aabest.com/en/default.aspx');"> <div class="float_l header_icon_map icon_aabest"></div> </div> <div class="clear"></div> </div> </div> <script type="text/javascript">
/* Forex Function */
function forexquote() {
quote($("#txtCurSymbol").val());
}
function forexchartquote() {
fxchart($("#txtCurSymbol").val());
}
function fxchart(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/forex/quote/chart.aspx?symbol=" + value;
}
function quote(value) {
if (value == "UDI") {
window.location.href = "/en/forex/quote/dollarindex.aspx";
} else {
window.location.href = "/en/forex/quote/quote.aspx?symbol=" + value;
}
}
/* End of Forex Function */
/* US Function */
function uschart(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/usq/quote/chart.aspx?symbol=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
function usquotewvalue() {
usquote($("#txtUSQuote").val());
}
function usquotewvalue2() {
usquote($("#txtCurSymbol").val());
}
function uschartwvalue() {
uschart($("#txtUSQuote").val());
}
function uschartwvalue2() {
uschart($("#txtCurSymbol").val());
}
function usquote(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/usq/quote/quote.aspx?symbol=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
// End of US Function
// Stock Function
function hkquotewvalue() {
var symbol = $("#txtHKQuote").val();
symbol = ('Code/Name' == symbol ? '00001' : symbol);
hkquote(symbol);
}
function hkchartwvalue() {
var symbol = $("#txtHKQuote").val();
symbol = ('Code/Name' == symbol ? '00001' : symbol);
hkchart(symbol);
}
function hkquote(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/stocks/quote/quick-quote.aspx?symbol=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
function hkchart(value) {
window.location.href = '/en/stocks/quote/detailchart.aspx?symbol=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
function hknewswvalue(value) {
var symbol = value;
symbol = ('Code/Name' == symbol ? '00001' : symbol);
window.location.href = '/en/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}'.replace("{0}", symbol).replace("{1}", "0").replace("{2}", "all").replace("{3}", "1");
}
function hknews() {
var symbol = $("#txtHKQuote").val();
symbol = ('Code/Name' == symbol ? '00001' : symbol);
window.location.href = '/en/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}'.replace("{0}", symbol).replace("{1}", "0").replace("{2}", "all").replace("{3}", "1");
}
function hknews2(value) {
window.location.href = '/en/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}'.replace("{0}", value).replace("{1}", "0").replace("{2}", "all").replace("{3}", "1");
}
/* End of Stock Function */
/* CN Quote Function */
function cnquote(value) {
if (GetDefaultQuoteSetting() == "QQ")
window.location.href = "/en/cnhk/quote/quick-quote.aspx?shsymbol=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
else
window.location.href = "/en/cnhk/quote/detail-quote.aspx?shsymbol=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
function cnchart(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/cnhk/analysis/tech-chart.aspx?shsymbol=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
function cnnews(value) {
window.location.href = '/en/cnhk/quote/stock-news/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/'.replace("{0}", encodeURIComponent(value)).replace("{1}", "0").replace("{2}", "all").replace("{3}", "1");
}
function cnquotewvalue() {
var symbol = $("#txtCNQuote").val();
symbol = ("Code/Name" == symbol ? '600000' : symbol);
cnquote(symbol);
}
function cnchartwvalue() {
var symbol = $("#txtCNQuote").val();
symbol = ('Code/Name' == symbol ? '600000' : symbol);
cnchart(symbol);
}
function cnnewswvalue() {
var symbol = $("#txtCNQuote").val();
symbol = ('Code/Name' == symbol ? '600000' : symbol);
window.location.href = '/en/cnhk/quote/stock-news/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/'.replace("{0}", symbol).replace("{1}", "0").replace("{2}", "all").replace("{3}", "1");
}
function shhkquote(s, type, passInMarket) {
type = type == undefined ? 'quote' : type;
var market = 'SH';
if (passInMarket == 'US') {
market = 'US';
s = ('Code/Name' == s ? 'AAPL' : s);
} else {
if (s.length == 6) {
market = 'SH';
} else {
s = ('Code/Name' == s ? '00001' : s);
s = '00000' + s;
s = s.substr(s.length - 5, 5)
market = 'HK';
}
}
switch (type) {
case 'quote':
$("#mainForm").submit(function (e) { return false; });
if (market == 'SH')
cnquote(s);
else if (market == 'US')
usquote(s);
else {
SetLTP(fullCookiesDomain);
hkquote(s);
}
break;
case 'chart':
$("#mainForm").submit(function (e) { return false; });
if (market == 'SH')
cnchart(s);
else if (market == 'US')
uschart(s);
else
hkchart(s);
break;
case 'news':
$("#mainForm").submit(function (e) { return false; });
if (market == 'SH')
cnnews(s);
else
hknewswvalue(s);
break;
}
return false;
}
/* End of CN Quote Function */
/* DZH Function */
function dzhquotewvalue() {
dzhquote($("#txtCurSymbol").val());
}
function dzhquote(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/dzh/quote/quote.aspx?symbol=" + value;
}
function dzhchart(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/dzh/quote/chart.aspx?symbol=" + value;
}
function dzhnews(value) {
window.location.href = "/en/dzh/quote/news.aspx?symbol=" + value;
}
/* End of DZH Function */
function toLang(v) {
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var search = window.location.search;
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (pathname != undefined && pathname != null) {
pathname = pathname.toLowerCase();
}
if (pathname.indexOf("/tc/") >= 0) {
$.cookie("mLang", "TC", { expires: GetExpiryDate(), path: '/', domain: subCookiesDomain });
window.location.href = pathname.replace("/tc/", "/" + v + "/") + search + hash;
} else if (pathname.indexOf("/sc/") >= 0) {
$.cookie("mLang", "SC", { expires: GetExpiryDate(), path: '/', domain: subCookiesDomain });
window.location.href = pathname.replace("/sc/", "/" + v + "/") + search + hash;
} else if (pathname.indexOf("/en/") >= 0) {
$.cookie("mLang", "EN", { expires: GetExpiryDate(), path: '/', domain: subCookiesDomain });
window.location.href = pathname.replace("/en/", "/" + v + "/") + search + hash;
} else {
window.location.href = "/" + v + pathname + search + hash;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: The scenario is not reproducible with the data you provide. You should provide the value you get from page.content property to check the .xpath method behavior in your case

Comment: I just run the code, it shows: (base) Jacks-MacBook-Pro:TestPython jacklau$ python TestXPath.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestXPath.py", line 16, in <module>
    getValue()
  File "TestXPath.py", line 13, in getValue
    print('value={0!s}'.format(value[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Let me provide the data I get, thx!

Comment: You should edit your question posting the value returned by `page.content` i.e the full html you get . One issue you should consider is that,  the HTML you get should be a well-formed xml for xpath to work  (web browsers can render HTML that is not well-formed XML)

Comment: I updated the code above, the link should be "/en" instead of "/tc", just like this http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/detail-quote.aspx?symbol=00371. And I add print (page.content) in the code. Since the number of line of page.content exceed the limit of stackoverflow, I cannot attach the output. Please try to get the output by "python TestXPath.py > a.html", thx!

Comment: I must insist that you post the value you are getting for the `page.content` property value with your question

Comment: I added part of the page.content above. thx!

Comment: I also try using response = urlopen('http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/detail-quote.aspx?symbol=00371')
print response.read(), but the output also does not look like what I see the code in browser by using inspect...

Comment: As you can see, the text you get through `page.content property` does not even contain the word `tbPBRatio`. I think you get message error ´"IndexError: list index out of range"´ because the XPath you use to seek through that text refers a indexed node `...\div[2]]` but there are not nodes at this point, because there are not nodes with an attribute `< ... id="tbPBRatio">`